# LDAP with SSSD: force user to change password - 'ShadowLastChange' not working

Tags: centos, ldap, authentication, password, sssd

I have CentOS6, with LDAP user authentication, using OpenLDAP and SSSD. I'm trying to force user to change the password. According to [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/255603/ldap-force-user-to-change-password) I tried to set `ShadowLastChange` to `0`, but it's just seem to be ignored when the user logged in with SSH.

In that question there is a warning that it might cause a bug of infinite loop of password changes requests, but I didn't get even single request...

There was another suggestion in that question,

> Try passwordMustChange attribute

But when I try to use it in my `.ldif` file, I get an `Undefined attribute type (17)` error

I also tried using `passwd -e username` on local Unix user, just to verify that it's working, and yes - that local user was forced to change password upon SSH login.

## EDIT

I've found `Password Policies` overlay in the [OpenLDAP doc](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html). Should it help? (if yes - is it the only way to solve my problem?)

## EDIT2

`Password Policies` doesn't seem to help either.

## EDIT3

A.

Actually, the Password Policy *is* working. First I tried to check it with [hp support suggesting](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02272032) - but the `ppolicy` didn't show in the log file.

But then I found good way to verify the Policy - set `pwdAllowUserChange` to `FALSE`, and see that the user cannot change password with `passwd`, with an error message from the server. Or, change `pwdMaxAge` to `1`, login, and see that the user get a password change prompt.

However, `pwdMustChange: TRUE` still doesn't help. After I change the user's password (either with JXplorer client, or from Unix shell `ldapmodify`), the user doesn't get password change notification.

Maybe I'm not setting the password as expected? In the `slapo-ppolicy` they say

> pwdMustChange

```
   This  attribute  specifies  whether  users must change their passwords when
   they first bind to the directory after a password is set or  reset  by  the
   administrator,  or not.  If pwdMustChange has a value of "TRUE", users must
   change their passwords when they first bind to the directory after a  pass-
   word  is  set  or  reset  by  the  administrator.
```

There seems to be a difference between `set` and `reset` a password. I tried to `set`. Maybe `reset` would help me. How can I reset a password?

Here's my policy:

```
dn: cn=default,ou=policies,dc=***,dc=com
cn: default
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdCheckQuality: 2
pwdExpireWarning: 604800
pwdFailureCountInterval: 30
pwdInHistory: 2
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 172800
pwdMinAge: 0
pwdMinLength: 6
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
sn: dummy value
pwdAllowUserChange: FALSE
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdMaxFailure: 5
pwdMaxAge: 999999
```

B.

(In response to Cameron Kerr's questions in comments)

It's CentOS 6.6.
And these are my /etc/pam.d/system-auth* files:

```
# cat  /etc/pam.d/system-auth
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so

# cat  /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

## EDIT4

OK, I've discovered that if I set `pwdReset:TRUE` in the User's entry, he's required to change password upon login. I think that it depends on PPolicy's    `pwdMustChange: TRUE`.

It's working, but I don't understand why it's the only solution I could find. (and a solution that Google couldn't find me!) Furthermore, it's strange that this change must be done with `ldapmodify` - JXplorer didn't even show me that attribute before I change it...

Comment: What version of CentOS are you using? Sssd has had a long history of bug fixes since RHEL 6.0. Though I don't recall that being one of them.

Comment: Also, it would be PAM driving the password change enforcement. What does you system-auth* etc files contain under /etc/pam.d/