# how to force ldap user to change password at first login

Tags: redhat, ldap

I have gone through the similar posts on the same question, yet couldn't find the correct answer to implement.

I need to force all LDAP users to change their default password set by administrator at their first login. I have tried `pwdReset:TRUE` option in user attribute and `pwdMustChange:TRUE` in default ppolicy. Both didn't help to resolve this. 
Please suggest the way, as how I can force users to change their own password at first login (after pwd reset by admin).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `setShadowLastChange = 0` in user entity.

[ldap force user to change password](https://serverfault.com/questions/255603/ldap-force-user-to-change-password)